# convert truthTable result into Boolean statement

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, truthtable

I am trying to convert back the result of the truth-table into a Boolean statement. 
For those who are not familiar I am going to write it detail.

I have a vector of string in a format like below. All string members inside vector have an equal length. Members are only composed by `-` or `0` or `1`.
for example vector v contain 3 member with the length of 5 for each member.

```
string vv[] = { "--1-0"  , "-1-1-" ,  "01-1-" };
std::vector<string> v(begin(vv), end(vv));
```

Each character of string represents another vector "A" member along with a Boolean operation. For instance,

first one `--1-0` is `(A[2] && !A[4])`

I would like to convert my above vector `v` into

`(A[2] && !A[4]) || (A[1] && A[3] ) || (!A[0] && A[1] && A[3])`

What I want to do is to have a function with vectors `v` and `A` as inputs and the return is above Boolean statement. I am sure you have noticed that `1` is `true`, `0` is `Not true` and `-` is don't care status.

**EDIT: I do NOT intend to solve a truthTable or Kmap. I already have the result. My result in the format of "v" vector. I want to create a link between V and A using Boolean statement.**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of string "-----" true or false?

Comment: '-----'  is nothing. if it comes along other string is equal to do union with nothing.

Comment: [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) with states {true, false, any} might be interesting in general.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I do not want to solve truth table. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the statement (as a string of code), or the *result* of evaluating the statement with a vector of boolean inputs?  You still have to say what the base case is if it said `vv[] = { "-----"  , "-----" ,  "-----" };`  Then you're using exactly no inputs from A.   You can "un-define it" (and say you don't care what the return result is, so the implementation could be true or false as convenient), or say it should be an error, or have a special "it was neither true nor false" return result (perhaps the return value itself is communicated with `1` or `0` or `-` instead of true/false).

Comment: @HostileFork I want the result of the of the evalueting statement. I am sure that there is no "-----" inside vector V. So no need to care about the special cases.

Comment: @ H'H - but what should return the function? A boolean value? A string value with something like "(A[2] && !A[4]) || (A[1] && A[3] ) || (!A[0] && A[1] && A[3])"?

Comment: @max66 my intend is the boolean value. however if I want to do it repeatedly for several vectors like 'A', it is a good idea return the string value and used it several time, or a pointer the evaluation statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that I don't speak English well but isn't clear to me what do you exactly want.

If you want a function that given a vector of `std::string` and a vector of `bool` return the `bool` value, according your indications, it's easy to do (hoping no errors made).

You use `std::begin()` so I suppose C++11 is good for you

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

bool singleStatement (const std::vector<bool>  & a,
                      const std::string        & s)
 {
   auto  ret = true;

   if ( a.size() < s.size() )
      throw std::runtime_error("invalid size");

   for ( unsigned  i = 0U ; i < s.size() ; ++i )
      switch ( s[i] )
       {
         case '-': break;
         case '1': ret &= a[i]; break;
         case '0': ret &= !a[i]; break;
         default:  throw std::runtime_error("invalid char"); break;
       }

   return ret;
 }

bool statements (const std::vector<bool>        & a,
                 const std::vector<std::string> & v)
 {
   auto  ret = false;

   for ( const auto & s : v )
      ret |= singleStatement(a, s);

   return ret;
 }


int main ()
 {
   std::vector<bool>         a { true, false, false, true, false };
   std::vector<std::string>  v { "--1-0"  , "-1-1-" ,  "01-1-" }; 

   std::cout << "statement is " << statements(a, v) << std::endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```